# Thread doesnt show xml

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a loading screen for my app, in MainActivity i have a thread called timer that starts next activity after 5 sec, but for some reason it doesn't show xml... when thread is not started xml is shown normally but as soon as i start thread screen is blank. Thread works, it changes activity but my "logo.xml" isn't shown.

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
Thread timer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logo);

     timer = new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            try{

                int ltimer =0;
                while(ltimer<5000){
                    sleep(100);
                    ltimer += 100;
                }
                startActivity(new Intent("com.JMS.sinktheship.MENU"));

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

timer.run();    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timer.run();
```

it is executed in the same thread that call the run method. Probably you wan to call `start()`.  In your code you are blocking the UI Thread for something like 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

blackbelt is correct, the view is rendered **after** the onCreate() is completely executed.

I would advise you to start the thread in the **onResume** instead and (very important) kill the activity when the thread ends by calling the finish() method (otherwise the activity will stay in the activity stack and will be rendered again via the back button).

Comment: I killed it in finally part.I'll try now in OnResume